# Create multiple databases in MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have an application that manages data for different organisations. How do I set up MongoDB so that each organisation upon registration, is assigned its own database ?

Currently I have a single database instance that stores data for all organisations such that on registration, an organisation has access to data belonging to other organisations as well which shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since the number of organisations registered is dynamic and the application has a single connection instance thus organisations can't be assigned databases independently rather they have to share that single database. 
Secondly, for each organisation to access their data independently it means their data has to be separated by unique identifiers and in essence the data is relational. Hence a Relational database e.g Postgre or MySQL is the ultimatum. 
Finally, to access data for a single organisation, all there is to do is perform a database query on the organisations data and filter based on their unique identifiers.